# How to get the Invalid value in the error message while using custom validator in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I having trouble in showing Invalid value in the error message
I have `messages.properties` file as follows

```
ProductId.exists.custom.validator.validation = A product already exists with product id ${validatedValue}.
```

and following is my custom validtor interface

```
@Target( { METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ProductIdValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ProductId {
   String message() default "{ProductId.exists.custom.validator.validation}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    public abstract Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Here is the implementation

```
@Component
public class ProductIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ProductId, String>{

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ProductId constraintAnnotation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        Product product = productService.getProductById(value);
        if(product!= null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

When I am running my application I am getting error message like 
`A product already exists with product id ${validatedValue}.` but I am expecting `A product already exists with product id P1234.` as error message

How to get the validatedValue in error message?

**Additional details**
I have used hibernate-validator:4.3.1.Final version and spring-webmvc:3.2.0.RELEASE
And I am triggering the validation in the context as follows

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator"/>
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Which version of Bean Validation / Hibernate Validator are you using? In which environment are you running and how is validation triggered?

Comment: Hi Hardy, I have updated the questions, I am using ibernate-validator:4.3.1.Final version

Comment: This should really work. Do you know which MessageInterpolator is used? The default one, provided by Hibernate Validator or a custom Spring one? In the former case I would interpolation of 'validatedValue' to work. In the latter it would not happen, since this type of interpolation was a custom feature of HV 4.3. You could write a unit test using HV directly, jsut to make sure that the problem is really there.

Comment: I'm also running into some nightmares here with Spring 3.1 and HibVal 4.3.1.Final. Looks like HibVal can't deal with the resourcebundle returning a default value with the same name as the parameter name in stead of an exception. This worked fine in earlier versions??

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what was the main reason for this solution I’ve used in my project – if to make interpolation work, or just use [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html) (that supports properties in UTF-8 and runtime reloading!) instead of the default one. However, this should work for you.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" primary="true"
      p:messageInterpolator-ref="messageInterpolator" />

<!-- Hibernate Validator which can interpolate the value being validated in the constraint message -->
<bean id="messageInterpolator" class="ValueFormatterMessageInterpolatorFactoryBean"
      p:messageSource-ref="validatorMessageSource" />

<bean id="validatorMessageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
      p:basename="classpath:/config/i18n/validator-messages"
      p:defaultEncoding="utf-8"
      p:cacheSeconds="0" />
```

And the custom `ValueFormatterMessageInterpolatorFactoryBean` class:

```
/**
 * {@linkplain FactoryBean} that creates {@link ValueFormatterMessageInterpolator}
 * with underlying {@link ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator} that uses the given
 * {@link MessageSource}.
 */
public class ValueFormatterMessageInterpolatorFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<MessageInterpolator> {

    private MessageSource messageSource;

    public MessageInterpolator getObject() throws Exception {
        ResourceBundleLocator resourceBundleLocator = new MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator(messageSource);
        return new ValueFormatterMessageInterpolator(
                new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(resourceBundleLocator));
    }

    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return ValueFormatterMessageInterpolator.class;
    }

    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }

    @Required
    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }
}
```

Note: I’m using Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final.