# Spring-mvc validation error not being picked from property file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

Using spring-mvc build in JSR303 bean validation and its working fine except for one issue, messages are not being picked from property file.

My Web-application is being created with maven and this is current structure

```
Main
      -java
      -resources
         -bundles
            -message.properties
      -webapp
```

### XML file

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <beans:property name="basenames">
    <beans:list>
    <beans:value>bundles/messages</beans:value>
    <beans:value>bundles/shipping</beans:value>
    <beans:value>bundles/payment</beans:value> 
     </beans:list>
  </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>
```

--
validator

```
<beans:bean id="validator"   
   class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
  <beans:property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
</beans:bean>
```

### annotation-driven

```
<annotation-driven>
  <message-converters>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter">
                <beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <beans:list>
                        <beans:value>image/jpeg</beans:value>
                        <beans:value>image/gif</beans:value>
                        <beans:value>image/png</beans:value>
                    </beans:list>
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
        </message-converters>
</annotation-driven>
```

### Java File

```
@NotEmpty(message="{registration.firstName.invalid}")
  public String getFirstName() {
   return firstName;
}
```

Some how on my JSP page, I am getting these messages `This field is required`, not sure what is issue
My Data class is having following structure

```
PersistableCustomer extends SecuredCustomer
SecuredCustomer extends CustomerEntity
```

Even after passing message source to validator, its not picking up message from custom property file.

Comment: You are missing `s` in the name of your `messageS.properties`. But I presume that is just a typo in the question, right?

Comment: @PavelHoral: that is a typo :)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146689/how-to-get-the-invalid-value-in-the-error-message-while-using-custom-validator-i/20912549#20912549), it’s the same case.

Comment: @JakubJirutka: I am not using any custom validator, only using validation provided by out of box

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi It’s not about it, the point is that you’re using non-default message source. Trust me, try my solution, it will work. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am taking a wild guess here... usually JSR-303 message interpolator is taking messages from `ValidationMessages.properties`. If you want your validator to use Spring's message source, you need to configure it that way:

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />
```

Comment: That did not helped..Even after setting as suggested..its still picking default values

Comment: How is your MVC infrastrucure defined? Do you just use `<mvc:annotation-driven />` or do you have some more fine-grained configuration? You might need to define *web binding initializer* with your validator. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer.html

Comment: I am using `<mvc:annotation-driven />`, update my post with desired detailed.Please have a look

Comment: Updated my answer... you can set `validator` reference on `<mvc:annotation-driven>` element.

Comment: I am facing strange issue still..though binding Result showing correct errors but still on the jsp its showing same default message  `<form:errors path="firstName" cssClass="error" />`